# how to bring variable from out the function? - node

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables, express

```
 app.get('/:id', function(req , res){
    var ID = req.params.id ;

    //converter...
    var dl = new Downloader();
    var i = 0;

    dl.getMP3({videoId:req.params.id},function(err,res){
        i++;
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else{
            console.log("Song "+ i + " was downloaded: " + res.file);
        }
           var videoTitle=res.file;

        });

    //i want videoTitle variable right here!
    //out of the function
```

});

this is very noob question but how to pull out variables from a function?
i am not able use this variable value out of this function.

FYI i am using node express moule..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible. `dl.getMP3` is an asynchronous method. It means that `var videoTitle=res.file;` is executed **after** the end of the first closure.

So if you want to send a response, you should place your code directly after `var videoTitle=res.file;`

Answer (score 0):

The best option is by using the `return` keyword. This immediately ends the function and brings out the variable name to the right of it. If you need more than one variable return an array.

```
function nameAnimal(){
  var animal = 'cat';
  return animal;
 }
var animal = nameAnimal();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue of scope.  If you declare the variable outside of your function and then set it inside your function, it should be available to you.

```
app.get('/:id', function(req , res){
var ID = req.params.id ;

//converter...
var dl = new Downloader();
var i = 0;
var videoTitle;

dl.getMP3({videoId:req.params.id},function(err,res){
    i++;
    if(err)
        throw err;
    else{
        console.log("Song "+ i + " was downloaded: " + res.file);
    }
       videoTitle=res.file;

    });

// videoTitle should be available here!
```